# Tensorflow data API and keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to setup a simple NN using the Dataset API and I am encountering an error. Right now I have the following:

This is the NN:

```
def get_model(input_shape, n_outputs):
    _input = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(_input)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)


    value_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='value_output')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=_input, outputs=[value_output])
    losses = {
        "value_output": 'mean_squared_error'
    }
    model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

This is the data I am using on the NN

```
def preproces(item):
        return item, 0.3    

instance = np.array([26])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([instance])
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess)
m.fit(dataset)
```

And I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_27/kernel:0', 'dense_27/bias:0', 'dense_28/kernel:0', 'dense_28/bias:0', 'value_output_9/kernel:0', 'value_output_9/bias:0'].

Not sure what this is missing, it's such a simple NN.

Thanks for your help in advanced

Answer (score 1):

I would mention that your data is inconsistent: if your input shape is [1] - your output shape should be [64].

I changed `preprocess()` accordingly.

But I was not able to reproduce your error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def get_model(input_shape, n_outputs):
    _input = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(_input)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)


    value_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='value_output')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=_input, outputs=[value_output])
    losses = {
        "value_output": 'mean_squared_error'
    }
    model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer='adam')
    return model

def preprocess(item):
        return item, [0.3]*64    

import numpy as np
instance = np.array([26])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([instance])
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess)
m = get_model([1], 1)
m.compile(loss='mse')
m.fit(dataset)
```